# Touch event equivalent to mouse down

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to use a mouse:down event on canvas like:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {}
```

How can I use touchstart event handler?

Comment: Take a look at the following events: `touchstart` (equivalent to `mousedown`), `touchend` (equivalent to `mouseup`) and `touchmove` (equivalent to `mousemove`).

Comment: i tried but touchstart doesn't work on canvas

Comment: `touchstart` can definitely be used with canvas. Could please you share your code? Would make it easier to identify what the issue might be.

Comment: You no need to use any touch events, as @almcd stated all the mouse events converted to touch events, Check for [more](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
// TOUCH EVENTS
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  // do_mouse_click_logic(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  // do_mouse_up_logic(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  // do_mouse_move_logic(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
}, false);

function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
  };
}


// MOUSE EVENTS
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var mousepos = get_mouse_pos(canvas, evt);
  // do_mouse_click_logic(mousepos.x, mousepos.y, evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var mousepos = get_mouse_pos(canvas, evt);
    // do_mouse_move_logic(mousepos.x, mousepos.y, evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var mousepos = get_mouse_pos(canvas, evt);
    // do_mouse_up_logic(mousepos.x, mousepos.y);
}, false);

function get_mouse_pos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function do_mouse_click_logic(x, y, page_x, page_y) {
  // Do your stuff
}

function do_mouse_move_logic(x, y, page_x, page_y) {
  // Do your stuff
}

function do_mouse_up_logic(x, y) {
  // Do yuor stuff
}
```

Comment: As in fabricjs all touch related events handled inside mouse event calls , you no need to add touch events manually, you can just use mouse events, everything will work.

Comment: yeah i could fix it inside mouse event calls. Thanks